# error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector2' to 'float'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm following a tutorial for the movement script for my sidescroller game but i encountered this error "error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector2' to 'float'"

this is the code, i suppose the issue is in FixedUpdate but i'm not sure

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed = 8f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        Flip();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to tag it as compiler-errors or 2d. 2D is unrelated, and compiler errors is a little broad. Unity should give you a line number where the error happened, as should your ide.

Comment: In rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity), you need to convert the second rb.velocity to rb.velocity.y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FixedUpdate you are trying to set the a vector2 y component to a Vector2, while it should be a float.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity);
}
```

Most likely you were meaning this:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
}
```

Here you set the y part of the velocity two the y part of the old velocity, leaving it the same. Here rb.velocity.y is a float and a new Vector2 takes two floats.
Hope this helps!